# jQuery get clicked id

Tags: jquery, json

I have a big bootstrap table. Each row of the table has two glyphicons, edit and remove. Every glyphicon-edit ID is built up of "edit + userId" (e.g. edit2, edit6, edit11), and similarly the glyphicon-remove IDs are made with "remove + userID". How can I see with jQuery which glyphicon has been clicked, and which user needs to be changed or removed?

This is the table:

```
<div>
    <table id="clientsTable" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="clientId">Client Id</th>
                <th data-field="name">Name</th>
                <th data-field="rate">Rate Per Hour</th>
                <th data-field="action">Rate Per Hour</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the Json code which gets used in the table:

```
public JsonResult GetActiveClients()
        {
            var clients = _clientService.GetActiveClients();
            var rows = clients.Select(s => new
            {
                clientId = s.ClientId,
                name = s.Name,
                rate = s.DefaultRatePerHour,
                action = "<span id='disactive" + s.ClientId + "' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' style='margin-right: 5px;'></span><span id='edit" + s.ClientId + "' class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>"
            })
            .ToArray();
            return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: you should write code here.

Comment: using **this** is one option

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').on('click',function(){
    var value = $(this).find('.glyphicon-edit').attr("id");
    var userId = value.substring(4, value.length);
});
```

Comment: While this maybe can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.

Answer (score 0):

Give a common class to all your golyphicon. Then apply a click function on them.

For eg, if all of them have class: `all-glyphs`

```
$('.all-glyphs').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   //your logic to remove or edit based on id.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

apply a class to suppose 'userEdit' to all edit columns and add data-id attribute and set it with userId's no need to concat string user with id's.

Now using jquery

```
$('.useredit').on('click',function(){
var currentid=$(this).attr('data-id');
});
```